# To Check Linked List as Palindrome Without using STACK

Tags: c++, algorithm

Below is the code for checking if **linked list** is **Palindrome or not**. The code that I have written is very **simple** and yet **lengthy**, As it has alot of **REDUNDANT** code. Can I **REDUCE** the **COMPLEXITY** of this code in terms of **Big O** keeping the same logic.

Just because I had to **skip** the **middle node** in case of odd linked list I ended up making the code redundant. Only extra part that I added in the code for odd linked list was

```
 `head_new = temp->next; 

// NEEDED TO SHIFT ONE POSITION SINCE MIDDLE NODE DOES NOT NEED ANY CHECKING!!!`
```

.

Is there any way I can make my code neat and less of redundant code.

```
void linklist::palindrome()
{
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *curr = new node;
    node *next = new node;
    node *head_new = new node;
    node *temp;
    temp = head;
    curr = head;
    int t = 0,flag=0,flag_new=0;
    while (curr != NULL) // calculating the length of llinked list
    {
        curr = curr->next;
        t++;
    }
    curr = head; // Making sure curr is pointing to the head
    if (t % 2 == 0) // checking whether the linked list is even or odd
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
    if (flag == 1) // if linked list is even
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < t / 2 ; i++) // traversing till the half
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        head_new = temp; // making sure head_new points to the head of other half
        for (int i = 0; i < t / 2; i++) // logic to do the reverse first half of the linked list
        {
            next = curr->next;
            curr->next = prev;
            prev = curr;
            curr = next;
        }
        head->next = NULL;
        head = prev;
        while (head && head_new) // comparing the reversed first half with the second half
        {
            if (head->data != head_new->data)
            {
                cout << "Not palindrome";
                flag_new = 1;
                break;  
            }
            else
            {
                head = head->next;
                head_new = head_new->next;
            }           
        }
        if (flag_new==0)
        cout << "Palindrome";
    }   
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < t / 2; i++)// logic to do the traverse first half of the linked list
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        head_new = temp->next; // ***NEEDED TO SHIFT ONE POSITION SINCE MIDDLE NODE DOES NOT NEED ANY CHECKING!!!***
        for (int i = 0; i < t / 2; i++) // logic to do the reverse first half of the linked list
        {
            next = curr->next;
            curr->next = prev;
            prev = curr;
            curr = next;
        }
        head->next = NULL;
        head = prev;
        while (head && head_new)// comparing the reversed first half with the second half
        {
            if (head->data != head_new->data)
            {
                cout << "Not palindrome";
                flag_new = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                head = head->next;
                head_new = head_new->next;
            }
        }
        if (flag_new == 0)
            cout << "Palindrome";

    }
}
```

Comment: Move out the linked list management to a class.

Comment: Why negative votes. I have written all the comments and everything properly. I need to know if complexity can be reduced keeping the same logic.

Comment: "Reduce the complexity" and "More neater way" (get rid of the "more", BTW) are two orthogonal things. So your question essentially makes it sound like: "Here's my code, please do whatever you can to improve it any every aspect that you have in mind". This is probably the main reason for the down-votes (although I personally didn't take part in that myself). Please ask a more specific question. Also, please indicate why you wish **not** to use a stack, because with the given data structure of a linked list, it **could** in fact make your code a lot neater.

Comment: BTW, as far as I understand the conventions on this website, the `gray-out` feature is meant to be used for code, not for emphasizing text. If you want to emphasize text, then use `**` on each side of it (I do realize that this comment is somewhat of a paradox though).

Comment: If it's a redundancy, then yes, you can get rid of it, by its very definition.

Comment: Ask your questions in the post, **not** in a comment.

Comment: @barak manos : I have done the editing as you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Split your function in sub functions would help.

Comment: Whole **if and else** part code is just the same except for one extra line that I needed to add to skip the middle node in case of linked list containing odd number of elements. So I was just wondering if there is some way out to merge the redundant code present in both if and else section.

Comment: Why isn't this a const memberfunction? And why don't you return the result instead of printing things to `cout`?

Comment: Ya I should use `return` .

Comment: @barakmanos : I am trying to solve questions in 3-4 ways so to improve my knowledge. That is why I wanted to implement it without using Stack. Using Stack will definitely make the code neater, and I will try that also. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following may help:

```
int get_size(const node* n)
{
    int res = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        ++res;
        n = n->next;
    }
    return res;
}

node* advance(node* n, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
        n = n->next;
    }
    return n;
}

node* reverse(node* n, int count)
{
    node* prev = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
        node* next = n->next;
        n->next = prev;
        prev = n;
        n = next;
    }
    return prev ? prev : n;
}

bool are_equal(const node* head1 , const node* head2)
{
    const node* n1 = head1;
    const node* n2 = head2;
    for (;
        n1 != nullptr && n2 != nullptr;
        n1 = n1->next, n2 = n2->next) {
        if (n1->data != n2->data)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return n1 == n2;
}


void linklist::palindrome()
{
    const int t = get_size(head);
    node *mid = advance(head, (t + 1) / 2);
    node* head2 = advance(mid, 1);
    node* head1 = reverse(head, t / 2);

    if (are_equal(head1, head2)) {
        std::cout << "Palindrome";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not palindrome";
    }
    // Restore list
    reverse(head1, t / 2);
    mid->next = head2;
}
```

Comment: I really need to learn the proper way of coding. I end up getting the result but the code turns out to be lengthy. Anyways your solution really helped.

Comment: By splitting long function into sub-function, the code becomes simpler to read/test/debug.